PLC Variable Order in Solution Instance
I have come across the following issue. The variable list PLC Instance Variables in the PLC instance looks good (right side), the addresses and offsets are correct. But in the solution view (left side), the order of the variables does not match the list. Have you also faced such a problem, in which direction should I look more?
I have looked at the .tmc file data, and the order of variables does not look sorted by address. In this picture TMC marked symbol has wrong position in list. BitOffset does not match with the symbols before and after.
In TwinCAT 4024.56 this works correctly.

Looks like it could be a bug with editor. If you clean, rebuild and reload project, does it fix it? TMC is usually generated with build command.

The project reload, rebuild did not help.
